# do you have to set aswell as get in java ?

Tags: java, arrays, get, set

Here is my working code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cars {

        String Type;
        String Make;
        String Model;
        int Price;      
        int NoDoors;

        public static void main(String [] args){

            ArrayList <Cars> vehicleArray = new ArrayList<Cars>();
            vehicleArray.add(new Cars("Car","Peugot","206",1495,5));
            vehicleArray.add(new Cars("Car","BMW","M3",34495,3));   
            vehicleArray.add(new Cars("Car","FIAT","PUNTO",3495,5));    
            vehicleArray.add(new Cars("Car","FORD","GT",41495,3));

            System.out.println("List of Cars :" + "\n");

            for(Cars car : vehicleArray){
                System.out.println("Type: " + car.getType());
                System.out.println("Make: " + car.getMake());
                System.out.println("Model: " + car.getModel());
                System.out.println("Price: " + car.getPrice());
                System.out.println("No of Doors: " + car.getDoors() + "\n");
            }           

            Cars lowestPrice = vehicleArray.get(0);
            for(Cars car : vehicleArray){
                if(lowestPrice.Price>car.Price){
                    lowestPrice = car;                  
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + "Cheapest Car : ");
            System.out.println("Type: " + lowestPrice.getType());
            System.out.println("Make: " +  lowestPrice.getMake());
            System.out.println("Model: " +  lowestPrice.getModel());
            System.out.println("Price: " + lowestPrice.getPrice());
            System.out.println("No of Doors: " + lowestPrice.getDoors() + "\n");

        }

        public Cars(String type, String make, String model, int price, int Doors){
            Type = type;
            Make = make;
            Model = model;
            Price = price;
            NoDoors = Doors;

        }

        public String getType(){
            return Type;
        }

        public String getMake(){
            return Make;
        }

        public String getModel(){
            return Model;
        }

        public int getPrice(){
            return Price;
        }

        public int getDoors(){
            return NoDoors;
        }
}
```

I was told that aswell as doing a get method i  had to use a set method too. But without the set method my program still works. I am just wondering if the set method is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't just add things because someone tells you to; you should add them when they're a requirement.

As your code is right now, it simply constructs your `Cars` (keep in mind that an object is typically singular, not plural) object through the constructor. If you never want to be able to change the properties of a car after it has been created then you're fine as it is.

A setter is there to provide manipulating access to the backing field. If you don't need or want this, then you shouldn't add it.

Sidenote: it might still be a good idea to add it but make it `private` instead. If you want validation logic (for example to check that the price is not negative), then this should be done through a setter.

Comment: Please accept the answer then ;) As an additional remark, the member field of your 'Cars' class does not conform to common java naming conventions. Please take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java .... and to reiterate Jeroens point: a constructor is a common way to initialize the fields of a new instance right from the start (and the only way to set instance constants). It's a nice way for setting a handful of important fields but gets cumbersome when many fields need initialisation. For this and to be able to manipulate them later, use Setters.